# SSH Server crashes randomly once in a week or so and comes back on when someone logs in directly

Tags: lenovo-laptop, remote-access, openssh, ubuntu-16.04, sshd

I have a `Lenovo ThinkPad E560 (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS)` stationed at our remote lab with a running `openssh server` that can be reached any time. Since last few months, the ssh server randomly crashes once/twice a week, I can still ping it but when I try to ssh, I get "`port 22 refused...network unreachable`" message. If someone physically goes there and just logs in, immediately it becomes accessible through ssh and fine for several days then randomly the laptop can't be reached through ssh and so on. I, even once uninstalled and re-installed `openssh server`, didn't solve the problem.

What is causing this and how can I diagnose this issue properly in order to fix this?

This question seems very familiar but it is not exactly what most of the people asking which is usually the crash of an ssh-session! I am asking about the ssh server.

Thanks a lot

Comment: First thing, look into the /var/log/auth.log file.  Look at the timestamps, comparing successful logins with unsuccessful ones.  If you want to see multiple log messages from multiple files, try running 'grep -rsh sshd /var/log |sort' and it will return all of the lines which contain 'sshd' in the /var/log folder.  That may be a lot.

Comment: It sounds like the machine is going to sleep, so you can't get to it from the network; but when somebody physically goes to the machine, they wake it up and the network becomes available again.  I'm not familiar with either ubuntu or Lenovo; are there "power" settings you can check?

Comment: @hymie  this is exactly what it looks like but it has been happening since the last couple of months, it was ok for the past 2 years. Also the strange thing is, if sleeping was the case then why take several days, usually computers go to sleep within a few minutes, at max, few hours. But this occurs once a week or once in 2 weeks.

Comment: @Christopher Hostage ```grep -rsh sshd /var/log |sort``` doesn't return anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Can you access any other services (VNC, a HTTP server, etc.) on the laptop remotely? If they act like the SSH server you may have a networking issue (a weird one at that)

Try reading through the SSH logs by

```
less /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh
```

Also make sure to read the other logs:

```
less /var/log/auth.log.1 | grep ssh
gzip -c /var/log/auth.log.2.gz | grep ssh | less
gzip -c /var/log/auth.log.3.gz | grep ssh | less
...
```

Also, try this just in case:

Boot into a live CD/whatever other Linux distro you have, and execute this

```
fsck -yf /dev/sdx
```

Replace sdx with your boot device's name, and boot back into the normal one.
[Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/801148/ssh-random-crashing#812544 ]

Comment: I looked at ```/var/log/auth.log``` at around the time when the crash happened, starting from 15 minutes before we recovered the crash. It crashed around Jun 19, 09:04 AM CDT, and we recovered it at Jun 19, 16:26 AM CDT, I looked at the logs in that period, but I see everything normal, this line: ```Jun 19 09:06:04 userid sshd[8**]: Accepted publickey for *** from 192.168.*.* port 5**** ssh2: RSA SHA256:**```, but during that time I was manually trying to ssh from that same IP 192.168.*.* and was getting "port 22 refused.."

Comment: ... also our automatic data transfer was failing. How come logs don't show anything wrong? I also checked ```less /var/log/auth.log.1``` last entry was on 17th June. Other logs you suggested are empty. Unfortunately I cannot do a physical USB boot as the laptop is in the US and I am somewhere else and we don't have anyone there right now.

Comment: Well I don't have any other ideas right now, so maybe it's a network problem?

Comment: I can ping the laptop successfully so the network is surely up and the laptop is not sleeping for sure, but not ssh-able!

Comment: I have a Raspberry Pi that does what you say your SSH server on your laptop is doing. Only my problem is fixed by a simple restart. Can you dump a few logs with information relating to the SSH server? Post them in a edit of your question. Also, in the month this started happening did you apply updates or suffer a crash on the laptop (that might have corrupted something)?

Comment: Also make sure it isn't set to go to sleep or something.